# Compliance issue with casino winning check

Tags: united-states, canada, check

I received a check from a on-line casino from Canada. I took it to my bank to cash and they sent it to collections. After about 2 1/2 weeks they sent it back saying compliance issue. What does that mean? And where can I cash it?   Thxs

Comment: Did you ask your bank what they meant by "compliance issue" in this instance? What did they say?

Comment: Was this a check you were expecting (eg winnings you cashed out) or more out of the blue?

Comment: Also are you in Canada, or the United States (or somewhere else)?